# Using Multiple date picker in application

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to use more than one date picker in single application, I have google searched and i get the answer for using date picker dialogue for picking the date.
But it gets complicated for my application, where i have to write the different code for every Datepicker buttons.  The code is,

```
 private void updateDisplay() 
 {
        Date = new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mDay).append("/")
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("/")
                    .append(mYear).append(" ");

 }
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
 {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
                {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    updateDisplay();
                    DisplayExpDate();
                }
 };
 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
 {
       switch (id) 
       {
       case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
          return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
       }
       return null;
 }
```

So please help me with giving more simple solution on it.

Comment: See my answer i did something for date and time picker, you can use do the same for two date picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DatePicker to create own DatePickerDialog that will be able to manage buttons per your requirements based on provided parameters. Here is [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) how to use picker to  create DatePickerDialog for Fragment. You should not have problems to reuse it for your needs