# Date Picker Call through through multiple buttons

Tags: android, button, datepicker

I am trying to Popup  Date Picker through calling two different buttons for an Android App, I am able to get the Date Picker Popped up for bStartDate Button but unable to get the bEndDate Button.

I am unable to get the whether they should be implemented in different files or same, or what is the possible problem with this piece of code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class StartDateActivity extends Activity{


    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID_END = 2;
    private int startYear;
    private int startMonth;
    private int startDay;
    private int endYear;
    private int endMonth;
    private int endDay;
    private String month;
    private String dateOfBirth;

    Button bStartDate;
    Button bEndDate;
    Button bPriority;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  Log.d("Some ", "Getting Called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bStartDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStartDate);
        bEndDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEndDate);
        bPriority = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPriority);



    bStartDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(1);
        }   
    });


    bEndDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(2);
        }
    });

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    if (bStartDate.getText().toString() != null) {
        try {
            calendar.setTime(df.parse(bStartDate.getText().toString()));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        startYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        startMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
    } else {
        startYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        startMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date.format(calendar.getTime());
    }


    //End Date Stuff ... 

    final Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    if (bEndDate.getText().toString() != null) {
        try {
            calendar1.setTime(df1.parse(bEndDate.getText().toString()));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        endYear = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endDay = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date1.format(calendar1.getTime());
    } else {
        endYear = calendar1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        endMonth = calendar1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        endDay = calendar1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SimpleDateFormat month_date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        month = month_date2.format(calendar1.getTime());
    }

/*
 * 
    if (cal_currentTime.compareTo(calendar) > 0)
    {
        //updateDisplay();
    }
*/
    }





@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
   if(id == 1){
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, startYear, startMonth,
                startDay);
   }else if(id==2){

         return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener2,endYear, endMonth,
                 endDay);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
 if(id==1){
    ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
 }  else if(id==2){
     ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(endYear, endMonth, endDay);

    }
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        startYear = year;
        startMonth = monthOfYear;
        startDay = dayOfMonth;

        String dateSetter = (new StringBuilder().append(startYear).append("-")
                .append(startMonth + 1).append("-").append(startDay).append(""))
                .toString();
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (dateSetter != null) {
            try {
                cal.setTime(df.parse(dateSetter));
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            month = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
        }
/*
        if (cal_currentTime.compareTo(cal) > 0)
            updateDisplay();
        else
            */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Choose Proper date format",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        endYear = year;
        endMonth = monthOfYear;
        endDay = dayOfMonth;

        String dateSetter = (new StringBuilder().append(endYear).append("-")
                .append(endMonth + 1).append("-").append(endDay).append(""))
                .toString();
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (dateSetter != null) {
            try {
                cal.setTime(df.parse(dateSetter));
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            month = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
        }
/*
        if (cal_currentTime.compareTo(cal) > 0)
            updateDisplay();
        else
            */
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Choose Proper date format",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};


private void updateDisplay() {
    dateOfBirth = (new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(startYear).append("-").append(startMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(startDay).append("")).toString();

    bStartDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(startDay).append("-").append(month).append("-")
            .append(startYear));

    bEndDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based so add 1
    .append(endDay).append("-").append(month).append("-")
    .append(endYear));
}



}
```

Comment: You have to create one date picker with all configuration of that for both buttons...

Comment: I am not getting how to modify.

Comment: Means where you give two listeners two dialog_id any same method and functions of Date Picker you can delcare only one or define one with same id and call on click of button showDialog(1) and remove all replicated conditions....

Comment: @NileshAgrawal refer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490540/using-multiple-date-picker-in-application?rq=1